# BATCH / CMD - findstr with regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have following line as a result of a scheduled task:

```
Last Result:                                            -1073741510
```

Now, I try to grab only for 0 (without any negative sign). I ended up with this:

```
echo "Last Result:                                            -1073741510" | findstr /r "Last Result: * 0$"
```

And I tried a lot of variations of the example above (i.e. without `$`, or with `</searchstr/>`, and so on, but that doesn´t work properly :-/

What am I making wrong?

Just for your interest, the line with the `Last Result:...` is the output of a loop, and I only want to exit the loop if a last result of `0` is found.

But `findstr` is a little difficult to get to work for me...

Comment: your `echo` echoes the quotes too - and the trailing space, so the string does not end with a zero, but a quote and a space. `echo Last result:     -123|findstr ....` (note: no space before the pipe) should do.

Comment: Show your loop - you probably also fell into the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, you´re right, the quotes were the problem: now the following works proper:
`echo Last Result:     010|findstr /rc:"Last Result: *0$"`
The findstr above does now only find a single 0 ;-) which is exactly what i wanted